# OverrideUserInterfaceStyle and willTransition not working in other class

Tags: ios, swift, overriding, ios-darkmode

I am trying to practice to use tab bar and navigation controller. However, I found out overrideUserInterfaceStyle and willTransition doesn't work in other class. How can I solve it?

Here my code where it will work perfectly:

```
class ViewController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTabBar()
    }
    func setupTabBar() {
        let aTab = UINavigationController(rootViewController: AController())
        aTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "cloud.sun.fill")
        aTab.tabBarItem.title = "A"

        let bTab = UINavigationController(rootViewController: BController())
        bTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "calendar")
        bTab.tabBarItem.title = "B"

        let cTab = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CController())
        cTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "text.badge.checkmark")
        cTab.tabBarItem.title = "C"

        let dTab = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DController())
        dTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "gear")
        dTab.tabBarItem.title = "D"

        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark // It has been called, working fine.
        
        viewControllers = [aTab, bTab, cTab, dTab]
    }
    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        //This will working perfectly
    }
}
```

But I create new classes where it will not working correctly, did I missed something? Here my code:

```
class AController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "A"
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark // Will NOT called...
    }
    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        //This will not working
    }
}
class BController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "B"
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light // Will NOT called...
    }
    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        //This will not working
    }
}
class CController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "C"
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .unspecified // Will NOT called...
    }
    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        //This will not working
    }
}
class DController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "D"
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .unspecified // Will NOT called...
    }
    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        //This will not working
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you embedding `AController`, `BController` and so on in another view controller, like `ViewController`, that sets `overrideUserInterfaceStyle`? If so, the child view controllers can't set `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` and also won't get notified in `willTransition` because it's "caught" and handled in the parent.

When a view controller overrides the interface style it also affects all children. For the child, it looks like the interface style never changes.